# Is the cross-sectional area of this object just the area of the 'top circle'? or do the angled sides and height matter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, aerodynamics

[image]

The diameter of the top circle is $0.08m$, diameter of base is $0.06m$, and height is $0.018m$.

I'm trying to calculate the drag coefficient of this object and hence need the frontal projected area, but I am confused about what the cross-sectional area really means for an object like this.

Comment: Hold the plate in your hand in dark and throw a beam of light axially through the base or top, and the shape of the shadow thus obtained is the shape of your cross-section shape.

Comment: You want the frontal area, thus use the bigger diameter value. The frontal area for drag is **just for reference** anyway meaning it represents a characteristic area, not the actual area.

Answer (score 0):

If the flow of fluid is perpendicular to the cross-section of the object (as shown in the figure above) then the frontal projected area of the object (as labeled by green color) can be computed as follows
$$\text{Area of top circle}-\text{Sum of areas of red triangles}$$
$$=\text{Area of base circle}+\text{Sum of areas of green triangles}$$
$$=n\times \frac12\left(2r\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\right)^2\cot\frac{\theta}{2}+n\times \frac12\left(2r\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\cos\frac{\pi}{n}$$

[image]

Where $r$ is the radius of base circle and $n$ is the number of pairs of angled sides and

$\theta$ is the angle between angled sides